# Pick multiple random values from Array in Ruby with repetition possible

Tags: ruby, arrays

How can I randomly pick multiple items from an array, where I can ensure repetition of elements is considered. `Array#sample` is not suitable as it only *seem* to pick set of unique elements:

```
>> array = (1..5).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>> 10.times.map { array.sample(2) }
=> [[4, 2], [5, 4], [5, 2], [1, 4], [2, 3], [1, 4], [4, 1], [4, 5], [3, 1], [3, 1]]
...
```

I can do the following to ensure repetition, but wanted to confirm if there is a better method that considers repetitive element picking too.

```
random_value_1 = array.sample
random_value_2 = array.sample
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Not sure what is the question. Do you want repeated values or not?

Comment: Its not clear? I want to ensure my random picks **can** have repeated values too.

Comment: Why not to shuffle array and pick elements from the beginning?

Comment: You could write that as `rv(array,n).zip(rv(array,n))`, where `rv(array,n)` returns a random array of `n` elements from `array`.

Comment: `my_array.shuffle[0..10]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get `n` possibly repeated random elements from an array, there's nothing else than

```
n.times.map { ary.sample }
```

Or if you're picking from a range

```
n.times.map { rand(1..42) }
```

There's really no need for a builtin way to achieve this; it's not common and the above are very legible.

Comment: I prefer `Array.new(n) { ary.sample }` for how it reads: "create an array of `n` elements, each of which is a randomly-selected element of `ary`".

Comment: May be I was very convinced that I was missing something. Anyways thanks for confirming such method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

The [`Array#sample`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) is designed to pick unique indices according to docs:

> The elements are chosen **by using random and unique indices** into the array in order to ensure that an element doesn’t repeat itself unless the array already contained duplicate elements.

So the best you can do, in my opinion is to pick 2 samples separately:

```
10.times.map { 2.times.map { array.sample } }
# => [[2, 4], [2, 2], [5, 2], [3, 3], [4, 5], [5, 5], [1, 2], [4, 4], [5, 3], [2, 5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `rand` if you want the possibility of repeats?

```
10.times.map { [rand(1..5), rand(1..5)] }
# => [[3, 2], [5, 3], [4, 1], [5, 4], [4, 3], [4, 4], [5, 2], [1, 5], [1, 4], [3, 2]]
```

Use `ary[rand(ary.length)]` if you want the selection to be explicit array elements

Answer (score 0):

```
this_array = (1..5).to_a
def this_array.pick(n=1)
  return n.times.map{self.sample} unless block_given?
  n.times{ yield self.sample}
end

p this_array.pick(10)
this_array.pick(4){|num| p num}
```

Note `pick` is defined only for this_array.

Comment: Patching objects is not something we see a lot in mainstream ruby. Still, it's good to remember that we can do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

```rb
array = (1..5).to_a

rand(1..array.size).times.map { array.sample }
```

Possible results e.g.

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[2, 3, 4]
[1, 4, 2, 5]
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```